# Не могу поставить видео вместо картинки в html

Tags: html, css, html5

есть такая проблема мне надо чтобы в данном коде вместо фото было видео, но при попытках поменять url или background-image на просто background не выходит.

```
            <article>
                <header style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520808663317-647b476a81b9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2073&q=80');">
                    <div class="upper-header">
                        <div class="mini-title">social network</div>
                        <div class="date-since">
                            <p><span class="date-value" id="sinceData"></span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </article>
```

ссылка на код
https://codepen.io/melchior_/pen/WNyGoZN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background для видео не используется, подключай через отдельный тег video и включай там autoplay